# php - why is my function giving me an output where the array is outputted as array(2)

Tags: php, arrays

im trying to sort even and odd numbers and im working on a script that takes an array and splits it up and makes two separate arrays with even and odd. however, my output makes the array print a '2' in the parentheses.  just wondering why this happens and how to make it stop?  probably simple.

```
<?php
$ints = [1, 2, 3, 4];
function  getEvens($evens)
{
    $even_array = array();
    $odd_array = array();
    foreach ($evens as $value) {
        if ($value % 2 ==0) {
            $even_array[] = $value;

        } else {
            $odd_array[] = $value;
        }

    }
    return array(
        'even' => $even_array, 
        'odd' => $odd_array);
}

echo '<pre>';
var_dump(getEvens($ints));
?>
```

Comment: What do you mean "print a '2' in the parentheses"?  That's the array length!  That's how `var_dump` works.  It's a debugging tool, and that's how it prints.

Comment: Because your return array has 2 elements even and odd

Comment: Try `print_r` or `var_export`

Answer (score 4):

I assume you are talking about this output:

```
array(2) {
  ["even"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    int(2)
    [1]=>
    int(4)
  }
  ["odd"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    int(1)
    [1]=>
    int(3)
  }
}
```

and your concern is the places where it says `array(2)`. That is part of how `var_dump()` works -- it just tells you how many elements are in each array. If you use `var_dump()`, you will always get that output.

If you don't want `array(2)`, use `print_r()` instead of `var_dump()`. It will give you this:

```
Array
(
    [even] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
            [1] => 4
        )

    [odd] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 3
        )

)
```

Comment: To add to this, the `2` in `array(2)` is the size of the array.

Comment: @Populus I actually address that in my answer.

Comment: sorry about that I missed it :P

Answer (score 0):

its because you are on vardump?

```
var_dump(getEvens($ints));
```

use print_r instead..

```
print_r(getEvens($ints));
```